# Use vim plugins in phpstorm ideavim?

Tags: vim, phpstorm

I use phpstrom for a few months, I really love it. Recently, I'm learning vim, I like its plugins, Esaymotion. Meanwhile, phpstrom also has a vim emulation plugin called Ideavim.

My question is that is it possible to use easymotion and other great vim plugins on phpstrom Ideavim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

IdeaVim only provides a superficial emulation of Vim (still the best one around IMO) that doesn't implement vimscript and thus doesn't support any Vim plugin.

But you can install other plugins that give you the features you want like [AceJump](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=).